# Where is the full list of XCTest functions documented?

Tags: xcode, xctest

I'm getting started with XCTest and only see bits and pieces of what is possible.

I know these functions:

```
XCTAssertEqualObjects
XCTAssertTrue
```

There is documentation in at "Unit Test Your App" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTestYourApp/UnitTestYourApp.html

Also, I see the header file `XCTestAssertions.h` and some webpage here is http://iosunittesting.com/xctest-assertions/ and another at http://appleprogramming.com/blog/2013/12/26/xctest-assertions-documentation/

But is there primary and reliable current documentation for these functions?

Comment: The names of the macros state exactly what they are for. For example the test `XCTAssertNil(a1, format…)` fails if `a1 != nil`. Actually the last link you posted explains the macros and what they are testing.

Comment: Yes, but it is not is not a primary resource and I can't be sure it is complete.

Comment: Why do you need a complete list. If it fits your needs, use it. Maybe Kiwi or OCHamcrest is what you are searching for. They are documented.

Comment: @FullDecent I know you posted two years ago, but just wondering any luck yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Xcode 8 Update**: XCTest now has [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest).

---

I was able to extract an [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc#readme) from the `XCTest` headers files and posted the [documentation online](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation). This has been last updated for Xcode 7.2.

[image: Unofficial XCTest Documentation]

Comment: Any chance of a Swift version? :)

Comment: @Joe Masilotti Any idea about this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766023/how-to-call-xctest-test-case-functions-by-order-in-xcode-8

Answer (score 0):

Updated documentation link is here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest

Comment: unfortunately link is broken