# How to call XCTest test case functions by order in Xcode 8?

Tags: function, xcode8, xctest

XCTest test functions was called in alphabetical order (before Xcode 8). With Xcode 8, I can not assume in which order the test cases are called by the system.

Can someone throw light on it?

Comment: In my opinion your tests should not depend on the order they are called.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make all test cases independent :)

Comment: @Confused I have checked this. but in xcode 9.1 its in alphabetical order only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tests within a class are run in a random order in Xcode 8. This encourages tests to be *independent* and *repeatable*.

---

I'm assuming that you want to run your tests in a specific order because they "chain" off of each other. For example, `test_A` logs a fake user in and `test_B` adds an item to the shopping cart. These type of tests should be avoided because they depend too much on each other. What if you want to run `test_F` alone? You shouldn't have to run `A` through `E` just to validate that `F` still works. Also, you could be introducing test pollution that is affecting other tests in ways you aren't yet aware of.

That said, having common or shared behavior between tests is fine, even ecouraged. You can put this login in the `setUp` method or [extract private helper methods](http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/) to handle specific events. For example, here's a *very* high-level example.

```
class AppTests: XCTestCase {
    let subject = ViewController()

    func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        login(email: "user@example.com", password: "password")
    }

   func test_AddingItemsToCart() {
       addItemToCart(21)
       XCTAssertEqual(subject.itemsInCartLabel.text, "1")
   }

   func test_Checkout() {
       addItemToCart(15)
       checkout()
       XCTAssertEqual(subject.totalPriceLabel.text, "$21")
   }

   private func login(email: String, password: String) { ... }
   private func addItemToCart(item: Int) { ... }
   private func checkout() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand the essence of independent test cases. This helps me a lot!!

Comment: Consider this scenario. I have two classes. One is for login and another class is for logout. Login class has three test cases in it and Logout class has two test cases in it. When I run the test cases via Product-->Test, Which class will be called first? Is it completed randomly selected by the system at run time? Can I define the order of the classes need to be called atleast?

Comment: I think my answer applies to your comment as well :-) You can move the helper methods out of the specific classes to share them between files.

Comment: So, should we also write classes independently like the test cases in it? Means, whatever class, whatever test case in it, can be called at any time independently.

Comment: Yep! Every single test and class should be able to be run independently of any other test and class, at any time.

Comment: What about test cases? (i.e. the classes themselves?)